# Trigger to validate room capacity

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a room capacity validation for a specific date using a before trigger.

This is the current trigger I'm using:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger my_insert_trigger before insert on my_table
for each row
begin
    if (select count(*) from my_table where room_type = new.room_type) > 3 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    end if;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

I currently have two columns in the same table which are date and room, this is my desired output

[image]

However this would not be the case because the trigger will still limit 'Single' three times regardless of date.

Answer (score 1):

> do a room capacity validation for **a specific date**

Just add the `date` to the control query:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger my_insert_trigger before insert on my_table
for each row
begin
    if (
        select count(*) 
        from my_table t 
        where t.room_type = new.room_type and t.date = new.date
    ) >= 3 then
        signal sqlstate '45000';
    end if;
end;
$$
delimiter ;
```

Note: because it has condition `> 3`, your existing code would allow 4 records per room. I changed that to `>= 3` so only 3 records are allowed per room and date, which seems to be what you are looking for.